# Ajax Yii submit form does not save

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm submitting a form in `Ajax` with `Yii`.

I have a form which list posts and for each post there is a link to the list of comments related to this post.

like this:

```
post 1  blabla       link to comments

post 2  blabla       link to comments

post 3  blabla       link to comments
```

when the user click on the link to comments, I render the related comments under the post + I create a form to create a new comment 
the link to comments  call the following action in the postcontroller

```
public function actionViewComment()
    {   
        $post=$this->loadModel();
        $comment=new Comment;
        $this->renderPartial('_viewComment',array(
            'model'=>$post,
            'comment'=>$comment,
        ));

}
```

the code of the submit button is the following

```
<?php echo CHtml::Button('SUBMITAjax',array('onclick'=>'send();')); ?>
```

the function send is doing the following

```
function send()
 {

   var data=$("#comment-form").serialize();


  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("post/Ajax"); ?>',
   data:data,
success:function(data){
                alert("Data Saved"); 
              },
   error: function(data) { // if error occured
         alert("Error occured.please try again");
         alert(data);
    },

  dataType:'html'
  });

}
```

The Ajax function is doing the following

```
public function actionAjax()
    {

$model = new Comment;



   if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
    {

        if($model->validate())
        {
           $model->save();
           return;



        }
    } 

 }
```

}

When I look to the response  with  Firebug,  it is blank.

Isn't linked to the fact that I'm using $model = new Comment;  in Ajax function ?

I tried not assigning $model but I got the error  variable not found.

What is wrong ?

Comment: Do you get 200 in firefox after submit via ajax?

Comment: Did you try to get a dump from $_POST to check whether data has been sent or not?

Comment: When I submit,  I got the success message 'Data Saved'             @Ali MasudianPour

Comment: Thanks for reply, and what about dump? CVarDumper::dump($_POST) ?

Comment: The dump give the data of the comment form                     Array
(
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [author] => ss
            [email] => ss@d.com
            [url] => 
            [content] => sss 
        )

)      Array
(
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [author] => ss
            [email] => ss@d.com
            [url] => 
            [content] => sss 
        )

)   @Ali MasudianPour

Comment: Can you show us your Comment Model rules()?